# Gerar um APK em um servidor

Tags: android, kotlin

Estava pensando em uma arquitetura que funcionaria da seguinte forma. O usuário iria ter uma série de parâmetros a preencher e gerar código automaticamente, aí ao **clicar** em um Buttom, seja ele em versão *web* ou *mobile* iria gerar um **apk** do aplicativo com os parâmetros passados.

Assim, provavelmente teríamos um *server* responsável por compilar e gerar o apk. Sabem se isso é possível?

O aplicativo teria que ser android nativo ou Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer. Duas possíveis abordagens são:

### Abordagem 1: Configuração via Gradle

É possível criar campos no Gradle e utilizá-los no app. Inclusive, esses valores podem ser passados como parâmetro via linha de comando na hora de buildar o apk.

Há dois tipos de valores:

- `buildConfigValue` - É compilado como um atributo estático da classe `BuildConfig`. Pode ser usado no código Java e Kotlin.
- `resValue` - É compilado como um `resource`. Pode ser usado no código Java e Kotlin e no XML.

No seguinte script Gradle, serão criados

- Um `resValue` do tipo `string`, com nome `hello` e valor padrão `HELLO, WORLD!`
- Um `buildConfigField` do tipo `String`, com nome `hello2` e valor padrão `HELLO, WORLD2!`
- Uma função `getPropertyValue` que tenta buscar uma propriedade no projeto. Caso ela não seja encontrada, retorna um valor padrão.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    resValue "string", "hello", getPropertyValue("str_hello", "HELLO, WORLD!")
    buildConfigField "String", "hello2", getPropertyValue("str_hello2", "\"HELLO, WORLD 2!\"")
  }
}

def getPropertyValue(propertyName, defaultValue) {
  def value = project.getProperties().get(propertyName)
  return value != null ? value : defaultValue
}
```

Agora será possível acessar estes valores no seu código:

```
message.text = resources.getString(R.string.hello)
message2.text = BuildConfig.hello2
```

O `resValue` pode ser utilizado também no XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
```

E para sobrescrever os parâmetros via linha de comando, bastaria invocar:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug -Pstr_hello="HELLO, CMD!" -Pstr_hello2="\"HELLO, CMD2!\""
```

O passo seguinte seria criar um mecanismo que mapeia parâmetros inseridos por um usuário em algum tipo de interface para parâmetros da linha de comando, invocar o assemble com estes parâmetros e coletar o apk gerado.

### Abordagem 2: Criação de scripts personalizados

Consiste em criar scripts capazes de buscar e alterar trechos de código, arquivos de resources, entre outros. Envolveria um trabalho um pouco maior para interpretar arquivos, mas é bem poderoso também.

No final das contas também seria gerado um apk com o `assemble`, para ser disponibilizado.

Esta abordagem pode ser utilizada em conjunto com a **Configuração via Gradle**.

---

Tem [uma apresentação bem legal da Heloisa Simon](https://pt.slideshare.net/imasters/intercon-2016-gerenciando-deploy-e-atualizao-de-450-apps-sem-enlouquecer), onde ela conta como a mobLee faz para gerenciar mais de 450 apps de forma quase totalmente automatizada. Eles usam um mix das duas abordagens apresentadas aqui.